# Change ActiveModel Serializer based on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

How can I have a certain set of controllers use a different adapter?

I think I can do something like this in a `before_filter`:

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json
```

Then on another set of controller's `before_filter`:

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = :json_api
```

The code won't be threadsafe though..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, you can specify the adapter in your controller action like that:

```
render json: @users, adapter: :json_api
```

It is of course not that convenient, as having a `before_action` in the base controller, but should be threadsafe.